# can't render 2D animation properly

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I can't seem to be able to render my 2D animation properly. Everytime it gets distorted and parts of it is not where it's supposed to be.

Anyway, I'm attaching a link below as soon as I get the Blend-Exchange page to work so that I can upload my .blender file there.

[image]

[image: render showing the problem] I'm attaching an image of the result here.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4026" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4026/)

Comment: I tried your file, it seems to work quite properly here... what's specifically wrong/broken?

Comment: I though it be something wrong with one of the meshes (see the black stroke on the tooth?). I checked them pretty thoroughly and can't find anything wrong with them.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to change the lamp settings from point to "hemi". Cheers